# data not getting inserted

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here am having two tables named services and payment and am having two forms for inserting values in to it..when i enter data in to services there am getting two rows names id and customer_id and i want to generate those values in to payment table while adding to the corresponding id.. This is my services table..

```
id  code     customer_id    particulars     serialno    complaint   
22  ORD00022    16             tv             100         ddfds     
23  ORD00023    19             GH             565          gfdg     
24  ORD00024    15             tv             122         sdfsd     
25  ORD00025    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg   
26  ORD00026    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg
```

This is my payment table

```
id      order_id    customer_id   actual_amount   paid_amount   balance     type
3          0            0              250.00       100.00       150.00     Cash
4          0            0              250.00       50.00        100.00     Cash
5          0            0              150.00       50.00        100.00     Credit
10         0            0              500.00       500.00       400.00     Credit
13         26           16             250.00       100.00       0.00       Cash
```

This my view page

```
<li> <a href="" class="make_payment" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".payment" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" customer-id="<?php echo $row->customer_id; ?>" >Make Payment</a> </li>
<div class="modal payment">
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_control/make_payment"   method="post" id="assign-form">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <h4 class="modal-title">Make Payment</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="box-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Amount</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_amount" id="total_amount" placeholder="Total Amount">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paid Amount</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paid_amount" id="paid_amount" placeholder="Paid Amount">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Balance</label>

    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="Balance">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Balance</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select name="type" class="form-control">
        <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
        <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> 
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="order_id" id="order_id">
  <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id">        
</div>


<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay">
</div>
```

My controller looks like this..

```
public function make_payment()
{
 $status = $this->Account_model->make_payment();
 if($status)
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Payment successful');
}
else
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Payment Failed');
}
redirect('account_control/view_order');
}
```

My model looks like this

```
public function make_payment()
{  

$paid = $this->input->post('paid_amount');
$total = $this->input->post('total_amount');
$balance = $this->input->post('balance');
$customer_id = $this->input->post('customer_id');
$order_id = $this->input->post('order_id');

$data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'actual_amount'=>$total,
    'paid_amount' => $paid,
    'balance' => $balance
);

if($this->db->insert('payment',$data))
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
}
```

iam getting an error like this

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'order_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `payment` (`order_id`, `customer_id`, `actual_amount`,      `paid_amount`, `balance`) VALUES (NULL, 'NULL', '100', '50', '50')

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/account/application/models/Account_model.php

Line Number: 196
```

This is my output view from the makep payment below action displays the modal

```
 S.No    Order #          Date   Particulars   Serial/IME No  Complaints    Action
  1       ORD00027   06/07/2016    led            11          sedsdf       make payment

  2       ORD00026   06/13/2016    cvbcv           5          tgtdfgfg     make payment
```

the last row i inserted in the payment table is the value i assumed that i should have to get

Comment: why are you using null as a varchar??

Comment: if varchar is not null then also the value is not getting in to it

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="order_id" id="order_id">   value is empty

Comment: i think your hidden field order_id is not being set....So,check it once

Answer (score 1):

In your form filed **order_id,customer_id** hidden filed missing `value` attribute

example:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="12" id="order_id">
  <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="454" id="customer_id">
```

Comment: yes..the value will not be same for all order_id and customer_id

Answer (score 0):

If you getting `Column 'order_id' cannot be null` means that your `order_id` is not posted or if is posted then it is null.
please check you are getting your `order_id` during the insert time or not.